# Usage of 'out of' in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

What is the meaning of `out of` in the sentence? Is there any problem if it is not used?

> They swindled local businesses out of thousands of pounds
>
> They swindled local businesses thousands of pounds
>
> Woman dealing with phony company scammed out of thousands of dollar
>
> Woman dealing with phony company scammed thousands of dollar
>
> New Scam Tricks Victims Out of  Thousands of Dollars
>
> New Scam Tricks Victims Thousands of Dollars

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the transfer of funds from the victim to the scammer.  I suspect it comes from these two definitions, per the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[out of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of)***
>
> **PHRASE**
>
> 1. Indicating the source or derivation of something; from.
>
>    *‘a bench fashioned out of a fallen tree trunk’*
>    *‘I get a lot of enjoyment out of teaching’*
> 2. Not having (a particular thing)
>
>    *‘they had run out of cash’*
>    *‘you're out of luck, mate, there's none left’*

I am reminded of the old joke:

> Person A: *Can you change a $10?*
> Person B: *Sure, I can change it from your pocket to mine!*

Comment: Similarly **out of pocket** meaning "having lost money in a transaction" (but lately an Urban expression for "unreachable").